# How do I find the application contentIdentifier in C# for a Windows Phone7 app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

There are several Launchers and choosers that take a contentIdentifier and defaults to the current application's contentIdentifier. Is there a way to find out the application's contentIdentifier with C# at runtime?

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier
```

I am trying to find out is the app is the signed and released version or if it's just a DEV build that's running. The contentIdentifier is set to the app GUID if it is the released version.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify your app GUID if you're calling the Marketplace... tasks to see details or review the currently running app.

If you leave ContentIdentifier blank the OS will look up your app GUID for you and these calls will work as expected.

If you call these APIs in testing you'll jump out to the Marketplace but you'll a messagebox error something like "can'tsearch get this information right now".

So for this scenario you don't need to know if you're on a dev phone or not.

If you still need to know the actual GUID I'm pretty sure you can find this in the WMAppManifest.xml on the phone in the appId attribute in the XML.

Comment: Yeah, I know that is the case. The MarketplaceDetailTask was just an example of the data(GUID) I am looking for. I want to know how to find the current application contentIdentifier/GUID.

Comment: OK I've updated the answer - you can search in the app manifest which will have the "official" GUID once published.

Comment: Is there an API in C# to access the AppManifest?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do this you can read it from the manifest.
The [coding 4 fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) has already implemented this and there's a good explanation at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Getting-data-out-of-WP7-WMAppManifest-is-easy-with-Coding4Fun-PhoneHelper

Comment: Matt, do you know if this will read the AppId correctly once the app is deployed via the Marketplace?  I understand the GUID gets changed as part of the submission/approval process

Comment: @ZombieSheep yes, the whole contents of WMAppManifest is rewritten as part of the certification process. It is the rewritten one which will be in the xap and then installed on the users device. It's the installed one which will be read.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I thought that would be the case but wanted to check.  I was about to submit a beta app to double check, but I don't need to do that now. :)