# MarketplaceDetailTask for an application that is not yet in the marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I have a Windows Phone 7 application that is not yet published and I neet to implement the functionality to invoke MarketplaceDetailTask and show the app's detail in the Marketplace.

The MarketplaceDetailTask needs a ContentIdentifier that corresponds to the GUID in Marketplace, but I do not know it yet (obviously). Some people suggest to use the GUID from the assembly but I checked my already published apps and the GUID after publishing is not the same as the assembly GUID.

I [found a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881071/how-do-i-find-the-application-contentidentifier-in-c-sharp-for-a-windows-phone7) that invoking the MarketplaceDetailTask without setting the ContentIdentifier works and the system fills in this property automaticaly but i do not think this works.

I tried this code in an app that is already in the Markeplace and it ended with an error

```
MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

So is there a way to use MarketplaceDetailTask for the application without knowing the GUID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested, don't specify anything for the task.

Just use:

```
var review = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
review.Show();
```

(Used in my actual WP7 app, working fine)

EDIT: Here's a link for the official documentation [that explains the use of this task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394030%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: @IgorKulman How did you tried? In the WP emulator, or with an actual app available in the marketplace? I just copied/pasted the code I'm actually using in my own ViewModel, I can assure you it works well.

Comment: I copied the code to an app, to the PageLoaded event of Mainpage.xaml, deployed on a device and run it on the device. The Marketplace was shown with an error message.

Comment: @IgorKulman yes, because Microsoft didn't validated you app: what did you expect the `MarketplaceReviewTask` to to? Your app, when deployed on your device, is not yet available in the marketplace.

Comment: I tried it on an apps that are already in the Marketplace, but ok, I will believe you

Comment: @IgorKulman I added a link to the official documentation that shows the usage of this task

Comment: The reason it isn't working, even though you tried it in an app that is published, is that the app running on your computer in the emulator, while the same app as far as you are concerned, is not the same app as the one in the marketplace.  First, the GUID is different (unless you changed the one in the emulator to match marketplace), so the emulator wouldn't know how to find your real app in Marketplace.  Additionally, the one in Marketplace has a certificate, though I don't know if this matters - it just comes to mind as a difference between the published version & the one in your computer.